# K-th element N*N sum vector

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search

I have an unsorted vector `V , |V| = N` and I need to find the `K-th` element in sorted vector

`S = {V[i] + V[j] | 0 <= i,j < N}, |S| = N*N`

I was thinking to sort ascending `V` and then compute only first `K` elements from `S` or sort descending and compute `(N * N) - K` if `K > (N * N) / 2` but for

`N = 50.000 and K = 2.265.604.247`

it's take 0.2sec in Java just to iterate from 1 to `N*N-K` and i need to do this in max 0.3sec. Someone can give me a hint how to do this?

Comment: If you have hard performance requirements, it might be best to turn to a profiler and analyze the runtime behavior of your code. If you can identify "hotspots" in there there you can post the corresponding code here to help improving it. With just a description of the algorithm, what are we supposed to do in order to "fix" the performance of your implementation?

Comment: Is the inclusion of `V[k] + V[k]` (`i = k = j`) intentional? (See the wording in tbukic's answer.) What is the time complexity of tbukic's approach? The first element of `S` is `2V[0]` (or `V[0] + V[1]` pending definition) - what are possible combinations for the second? How could one efficiently enumerate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my idea of the solution.
I think it should be lot faster than calculating everything, and that you should consider it.

---

`V` is sorted vector length `n`, and we want to find `k`-th biggest number of Cartesian product `VxV = {v1+v2|,v1,v2∈V}`.

We'll use searching method similar to binary search to find wanted number.

Note this:
For every number `M`, `M = m+m, m < max{v|v∈ V}` we define set `X = {x ∈ VxV, x<=m+m=M}`. It's easy to find `|X|` and `max{X}` using this:

1. Loop through the `V` with index `i`.
2. For every `v = V[i]`, `v' = M-V[i]`.
3. Using binary search, find index `j` so: `w = V[j] <= v'` and `j+1>n OR V[j+1] > v'`.
4. For each looping with `i`, sum all calculated `j`. That is number elements in `X`.
5. `max{X}` is the biggest value of `v+w` calculated for every pair of `i` and `j`, so you need to remember it, too.

By selecting different values of `M` (use binary search method), you can find value of `M` for which `|X| = k`. When you've found it, `max{X}` is your solution.

---

PS. I've deleted my previous answer because it contained part I thought I had deleted, and because I've written it for multiplications of `V`'s elements instead of additions. Sorry for inconvenience, anyone.